# Making remote layout changes in Filemaker

Tags: filemaker

I am using Filemaker 17 pro advanced to make layout changes to a filemaker 16 pro advanced server.  When opening a filemaker database remotely through show hosts, then making layout changes on the opened database:  Will modifications to the layout be updated on the server without re-uploading to FileMaker server?

[image: screenshot of view hosts in filemaker**view hosts**]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, assuming your account gives you such access. That said, it is not recommended to do live updates on production systems.

Comment: I asked this because it seemed rather insecure to me in the first place to be able to even gain access to the filemaker server and open a project without credentials.

I see that there is an option to Upload to Filemaker Server under File -> Sharing -> Upload.  What is the use of this?  Is it only for an initial upload of a database?

Comment: Yes, it is for the initial upload. You should set up accounts and passwords to secure the access.